# Find the number of times a given weekday falls in a specified year

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to write a program that will take two parameters: the weekday and year.  The program should then print out the number of times that the weekday specified by the user falls on the first of each month in the given year.  I can do it for one month, but how do I iterate through all twelve months.

Here is my code:

```
public class dateCheck {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String weekday="Sunday";
    int year=2017;

 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 01);
     cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
     cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

     cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
     Date firstDayOfMonth = cal.getTime();  

     DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEE");   
     System.out.println("First Day of Month: " + sdf.format(firstDayOfMonth));

     if(weekday.equals(sdf.format(firstDayOfMonth))){
         System.out.println("This day falls on the first of the month");
     }
     else
         System.out.println("This day does not fall on the first of the month");


    }


}
```

I think I could use a for loop but I am not sure how to iterate through the months.  I am new to Java.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are able to use Java 8 there is no reason to still use `Calendar`. Here is a version using the [new Date and Time api](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html):

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class WeekdayCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String weekday = "Sunday";
        int year = 2017;
        int occurrences = 0;

        for (Month month : Month.values()) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
            DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek();
            if (dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH).equals(weekday)) {
                occurrences++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(weekday + " is the first day of a month " + occurrences + " times in " + year);
    }
}
```

Update:

The initial version uses `dayOfWeek.getDisplayName` to be in line with your comparison. The smarter choice (as pointed out in the comments) would be to convert the user input to a `DayOfWeek` instance as well.

Here is a modified approach which currently works for inputs like "sunday", "Sunday" or "sUnDaY", but can be tweaked for more sophisticated logic by enhancing the `toDayOfWeek` method:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;

public class WeekdayCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userInput = "Sunday";
        DayOfWeek inputDayOfWeek = toDayOfWeek(userInput);
        int inputYear = 2017;
        int occurrences = 0;

        for (Month month : Month.values()) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(inputYear, month, 1);
            DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek();
            if (dayOfWeek == inputDayOfWeek) {
                occurrences++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(userInput + " is the first day of a month " + occurrences + " times in " + inputYear);
    }

    private static DayOfWeek toDayOfWeek(String dayString) {
        return DayOfWeek.valueOf(dayString.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I think I’d use `for (Month month : Month.values())`. I might also require a `DayOfWeek` enum constant (or convert to one) so I avoided the `getDisplayName()` call in each iteration.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thought about using `Month` but didn't see the second `of` method until just now - will change it. The ugly `getDisplayName()` is kind of on purpose to keep it in line with the original comparison. But I agree that an enum would be the better choice.

Comment: Yes, see your point. The original code could have required or converted to `Calendar.SUNDAY` and used `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`, but didn’t, so your code is more in line with how it did.

Comment: I've added a second approach using the enum if the string comparison was not intentional.

Comment: There’s a great coherence between the newer classes and enums. Once you get used to it, you will find it natural to expect that you can pass a `Month` to the factory methods of the other classes.

Comment: Nice conversion method!

Comment: As Ole V.V. suggested, I would focus on using the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum rather than a string of name of day-of-week.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach. I use two methods. One that has a loop that iterates over all the months, and a second used inside of it, that returns a boolean if the condition is true. The condition being same weekday as the one that the user looks for. If its true it makes the field *counter* increment by one.
Im using the Calendar.set() method to first set it to the beginning of the year, then Calender.roll(), to advance one month per iteration.
I hope it makes sense

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MyCalendar {
    private Calendar calendar;
    private int counter;
    private DateFormat frm;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCalendar cal = new MyCalendar();
        int answer = cal.firstPerMonth(2017, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        System.out.println("total" + answer);
    }

    public MyCalendar() {
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        frm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd 'is a' EEE");
    }

    public int firstPerMonth(int year, int dayOfWeek) {
        counter = 0;
        calendar.set(2017, 0, 1);
        for(int x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
            if(checkIfSameDay(dayOfWeek)) {
                counter++;
            }
            calendar.roll(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public boolean checkIfSameDay(int dayOfWeek) {
        if(dayOfWeek == calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
            System.out.println(frm.format(calendar.getTime()));
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would iterate over 12 consecutive months (this is because `Calendar.JANUARY` and all the remaining months are just consecutive `int`s starting from 0:

```
    String weekday = "Sunday";
    int year = 2017;

    for (int month = Calendar.JANUARY; month <= Calendar.DECEMBER; month++) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 01);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        Date firstDayOfMonth = cal.getTime();

        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEE");
        System.out.println("First Day of Month: " + sdf.format(firstDayOfMonth));

        if (weekday.equals(sdf.format(firstDayOfMonth))) {
            System.out.println("This day falls on the first of the month");
        } else
            System.out.println("This day does not fall on the first of the month");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: Instead of passing `Calendar.JANUARY`, pass the integer value for the month.

```
public class dateCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String weekday = "Sunday";
        int year = 2017;
        int month = 0;

        for (month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 01);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            Date firstDayOfMonth = cal.getTime();

            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEE");
            System.out.println("First Day of Month " + month.toString() + ": " + sdf.format(firstDayOfMonth));

            if (weekday.equals(sdf.format(firstDayOfMonth))) {
                System.out.println("This day falls on the first of the month");
            } else
                System.out.println("This day does not fall on the first of the month");
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses the `.roll(...)` method of `Calendar`. It demonstrates how to increment the `cal` instance.

```
final static DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEE");

static boolean isOnFirst(String weekday, Calendar month)
{
    String dom = sdf.format(month.getTime());
    return (weekday.equalsIgnoreCase(dom));
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // test data: could be obtained from the user
    String weekday = "Sunday";
    int year = 2017;

    // construct the initial instance
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

    // our (poorly named) counter for how often it appears
    int num = 0;

    // loop over all of the months in the year
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        // if we are on the first day of the month, increment our counter
        if (isOnFirst(weekday, cal)) {
            ++num;
        }

        // advance by one month
        cal.roll(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    }

    // output results
    System.out.println(weekday + " appears " + num 
            + " times on the first day of the month in " + year);
}
```

output:

> Sunday appears 2 time(s) on the first day of the month in 2017

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   String weekday = "Sunday";
    int year = 2017;

    int numOfWeekDayAsFirstDayInMonth = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 01);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, i);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        Date firstDayOfMonth = cal.getTime();

        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEE");

        if (weekday.equals(sdf.format(firstDayOfMonth))) {
            numOfWeekDayAsFirstDayInMonth++;
        }

    }

    System.out.printf("Week day %s occured %d times in year %s as first day of all monthes", weekday, numOfWeekDayAsFirstDayInMonth, year);
```

output:

```
Week day Sunday occured 2 times in year 2017 as first day of all monthes
```